# Finding mean of 2D tensor groupwise in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to find a group-wise row-wise mean of a 2D tensor in Tensorflow. I will show through an example what I want to achieve. For example, if there is a Tensor `A=[[0,1],[1,3],[2,6],[3,1],[2,7]]` and a list of lists that show the groups `L=[[0,1],[3],[2,4]]`. So in the list `L`, there are 3 lists, so there will be 3 groups. So the output should be a 3 X 2 matrix with the first row being mean of row 0,1 of `A`, second row being mean of row 3 of `A` and third row being mean of row 2,4 of `A`. I need the operation to be generalized to any arbitrary `A`, `L`. I can build an operation for Numpy but I could not find any method for Tensorflow.

Comment: tf.segment_mean when using another encoding or tf.scatter_add